# Como impedir que entren al login una vez que la sesión este iniciada con Django

Tags: python, django, url

Hola tengo un problema simple pero no sé como resolverlo, lo que pasa es que quisiera saber si existe algun método o algo que impida al usuario entrar al login si ya tiene la sesión abierta.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView, LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('estudiante/', include('volder_app.urls')),
    path('', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name="login"), /*<------- */
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name="logout"),
]
```

La versión de *Django* que utilizo es la 2.2, y el único lugar en el que llamo la URL es desde ahi, luego solo el template de login.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes simplemente utilizar [`redirect_authenticated_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/) en `as_view()`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView, LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('estudiante/', include('volder_app.urls')),
    path('', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True), name="login"),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name="logout"),
]
```

Recuerda establecer la url de destino en `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`